# Fail to understand the usage of partial argument in Flax Resnet Official Example

Tags: jax, flax

I have been trying to understand [this official example](https://this%20official%20example). However, I am very confused about the use of `partial` in two places.

For example, in line 94, we have the following:

```
conv = partial(self.conv, use_bias=False, dtype=self.dtype)
```

I am not sure why it is possible to apply a partial to a class, and where later in the code we fill in the missing argument (if we need to).

Coming to the final definition, I am even more confused. For example,

```
ResNet18 = partial(ResNet, stage_sizes=[2, 2, 2, 2],
               block_cls=ResNetBlock)
```

Where do we apply the argument such as `stage_size=[2,2,2,2]`?

Thank you

Comment: Your link seems malformed. Perhaps you meant to link to here? https://github.com/google/flax/blob/main/examples/imagenet/models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functools.partial` will partially evaluate a function, binding arguments to it for when it is called later. here's an example of it being used with a function:

```py
from functools import partial

def f(x, y, z):
  print(f"{x=} {y=} {z=}")

g = partial(f, 1, z=3)
g(2)
# x=1 y=2 z=3
```

and here is an example of it being used on a class constructor:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyClass(NamedTuple):
  a: int
  b: int
  c: int

make_class = partial(MyClass, 1, c=3)
print(make_class(b=2))
# MyClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

The use in the flax example is conceptually the same: `partial(f)` returns a function that when called, applies the bound arguments to the original callable, whether it is a function, a method, or a class constructor.

For example, the `ResNet18` function created [here](https://github.com/google/flax/blob/e9edd2ab1ca77e21e7a8b9ca59d2b955eb1bbd16/examples/imagenet/models.py#L123-L124):

```py
ResNet18 = partial(ResNet, stage_sizes=[2, 2, 2, 2],
                   block_cls=ResNetBlock)
```

is a partially-evaluated `ResNet` constructor, and the function is called in a test [here](https://github.com/google/flax/blob/e9edd2ab1ca77e21e7a8b9ca59d2b955eb1bbd16/examples/imagenet/models_test.py#L52):

```py
  @parameterized.product(
      model=(models.ResNet18, models.ResNet18Local)
  )
  def test_resnet_18_v1_model(self, model):
    """Tests ResNet18 V1 model definition and output (variables)."""
    rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
    model_def = model(num_classes=2, dtype=jnp.float32)
    variables = model_def.init(
        rng, jnp.ones((1, 64, 64, 3), jnp.float32))

    self.assertLen(variables, 2)
    self.assertLen(variables['params'], 11)
```

`model` here is the partially evaluated function `ResNet18`, and when it is called it returns the fully-instantiated `ResNet` object with the parameters specified in the `ResNet18` partial definition.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answer regarding jax and flax!